# Run a Drupal website offline (±without server)? --- E.g. hand it over on a usb-stick / by mail? --- Run it from the HD, while retaining functionality?

Tags: 7

## Why run Drupal offline?

Since I use free webhosting, I don't have 100% up-time, so I started wondering whether I could maintain such Drupal functionality, while at the same time working offline.

## An example of an application

- In general, I am talking about a more or less operational website here.

E.g., my own quest at the moment: I want to let people fill in a couple of words/lines on a Drupal website by clicking on hyperlinks at specific points in a HTML article which is created on a Drupal website - and have the input of the people saved somewhere. *(I still have to find the right module / way of achieving this by the way)*

---

## 1 small step to think, 1 giant leap in technology?

Any thoughts on how to go about this? Perhaps letting people "run" / temporarily host the website from their own computers? (P.S.: I would rather like to keep things as WYSIWYG as possible.)

I am not experienced in this matter, but what do you think would be perhaps missing to pull this off: the handling or online hosting of a MySQL-database; something that has to do with PHP;...?

- Perhpas, cf. the following question about [offline MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474814/mysql-database-offline-use).

Comment: I am nearly positive I have run Drupal using Server2Go from a USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal is too large a project to be run on slim architecture or dumb terminals. If you're going to buy a USB stick (memory) to store Drupal then buy a "computer stick" and run Drupal off of Sqlite on the stick, for example a Gumstix product with Ubuntu on it $200 USD is hardly more expensive then an expensive large USB memory stick. https://store.gumstix.com/index.php/products/283/

Comment: So it would be possible; by running something like [Sqlite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) on a USB stick, but it would crash / slow down / freeze? --- How about running the Drupal website from a regular hard drive (HD)? Is it possible with Sqlite, just an easy-install and nothing else needed? --- Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: Drupal is not too large for a slim hardware. I have just placed Drupal in node-webkit using php-webkit and placed in on a USB stick (on Mac) and I am about to do the same thing for PCs. It's using SQLite for the DB. The web server at that point can be anything already available form nodejs or even the php embedded web server. Yes ... the PHP embedded web server is fit enough to run Drupal. The embedded server is not recommended for production yet.